# CakePhp 3.0 slow with shared host (hostgator)

Tags: cakephp, caching, server

After doing a normal install of cakePHP 3.1 on a server from hostgator I am getting responses from 50 sec or 1 minutes to load the site.

I tried redo the cache permissions.

Comment: have you a solution i have the seam problem

Comment: Same here, guess someone should've found the solution!

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: I have also the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with hostgator is the version of MySQL. They use an older version and present a delay with the "information_schema". 
My solution was comment the entire call for "information_schema" which is NOT the ideal but works.

the path of this file is: {my_app}/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/MysqlSchema.php

```
public function describeForeignKeySql($tableName, $config)
{
    /* Commented by hsoberon to fix the delay in HOSTGATOR */ 
    // $sql = 'SELECT * FROM information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
    //     INNER JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints AS rc
    //     ON (
    //         kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    //         AND kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    //     )
    //     WHERE kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = ? AND rc.TABLE_NAME = ?';

    // return [$sql, [$config['database'], $tableName, $tableName]];
}
```

This way the delay is fix and everything has been working good. so far.